# Comparing values (pd)

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: typos

so I have to look at a kindergarden to see if someone went home happy.
There is a happy column:
If they went home happy there's a 1
If they went home unhappy there's a 0

I have to compare that to age groups:
There is a age_group column:
"20 to 40"
"40 to 60"
"60 to 80"

Now I want to compare if they went home happy and the age group.

Can someone help me please? :-)

Comment: You should write the second for loop in the next line "for n in df["happy"]: for k in df["age_group"]:" Also, you typed k = "20-40:". It should be "k == "20-40:"

Comment: I've posted the answer for you. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
happy_group1 = 0
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]["happy"] == "1" and row[1]["age_group"] == "20-40":
        happy_group1+=1
    else:
        pass
print(happy_group1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
happy_group1 = 0
for n in df["happy"]:
    for k in df["age_group"]:
        if n == 1 and k == "20-40":
            happy_group1 += 1
        else:
            pass
print(happy_group1)
```